# Android Room: different entity classes in one database

Tags: android, android-room

I have a database:

```
@androidx.room.Database(entities = {Assertion.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class Database extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract AssertionDao assertionDao();
}
```

... and an entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Assertion {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NonNull
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "pseudonym")
    public byte[] nym;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "message")
    public String msg;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "signature")
    public byte[] signature;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "gValue")
    public byte[] g;

    public Assertion(CipherParameters cipherNym, String msg, byte[] signature) {
        this.nym = MainActivity.getBytesFromCipher(cipherNym);
        this.msg = msg;
        this.signature = signature;
        this.g = ((BLS01KeyParameters)cipherNym).getParameters().getG().toBytes();
    }

    public Assertion() {}
}
```

`Assertion`s will be compressed periodically to generate a `CompressedAssertion` which contains a `signature`, an array/list of `nym`s, an array/list of `msg`s, and an array/list of `g`s.

Currently, my `CompressedAssertion` is like (it will find those arrays/lists from the first database):

```
@Entity
public class CompressedAssertion {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    public byte[] signature;

    @TypeConverters(Converters.class)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ids")
    public List<Integer> ids;

    public CompressedAssertion(byte[] signature, List<Integer> ids) {
        this.signature = signature;
        this.ids = ids;
    }

    public CompressedAssertion() {}
}
```

...stored in another database:

```
@androidx.room.Database(entities = {CompressedAssertion.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
public abstract class CompressedDatabase extends RoomDatabase{
    public abstract CompressedAssertionDao compressedAssertionDao();
}
```

Is there any way to achieve similar functionality with ONE database, instead of two?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question, if you need two entities in the same database then surely you would just specify multiple entities with `entities = {C1.class, ...}`? Why did you need the second database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use:-

```
@androidx.room.Database(entities = {Assertion.class,CompressedAssertion.class}, version = 1, ....
```

and then don't have the `CompressedDatabase` class

i.e. use (ONLY) :-

```
@androidx.room.Database(entities = {Assertion.class,CompressedAssertion.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
public abstract class Database extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract AssertionDao assertionDao();
    public abstract CompressedAssertionDao compressedAssertionDao();
}
```

- in Short you can have a database contain many tables. Using single tables is rare. Using multiple databases each with one table is even rarer and introduces complications and restrictions and inefficiencies.